# I am trying to install deluge

Tags: apt, dpkg, ubuntu-mate

```
me@hp:~$ sudo apt-get install deluge

[sudo] password for me:

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

help me how to fix this

Comment: The clue is in the error message "you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem"

Comment: Have you tried running the command that it says that you should run to correct the problem?

Comment: it prompts eula agreement

Comment: dont know how to terminate it

Comment: and i have closed the terminal. and trying to install another package. but it says another program is using it. how to know which one and how to close that.